# Is there an added-value to log JSON data to Elasticsearch via Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am reviewing my logging strategy (logs from OS and applications which log to syslog, and from my own applications where I can freely decide what and where to log). Not having a lot of experience with Logstash I was wondering whether there is an added value to log JSON data through it (as opposed to directly sending them to Elasticsearch).

The only advantage I could think of is that logging could be consistently to `stdout` (and then be picked up by syslog), and consistently sent to Logstash (as syslog), to be analyzed there (Logstash would know that data from application *myapp.py* send raw JSON, for instance).

**Are there other advantages to use Logstash as an intermediate?** (security aspects are not important in that context).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of advantages in using Logstash even when your data is already a JSON Object.

For example:

- **HTTP Compression**: When logstash outputs to elasticsearch, you have the option to use http compression, which greatly reduces the size of the requests and the use of the bandwith.
- **Persistent Queue**: Logstash allows you to have a persistent queue, in memory or in disk, to save the events when it cannot connect with elasticsearch for some reason.
- **Data Manipulation**: You can use filters to change and enrich your data, for example you can remove and add fields, change the name of fields, use a geoip filter on a ip field etc.